# How do I use helium properly

Tags: robocraft

I'm building a **robo** and I'm messing around with **helium** and my **robo** keeps flipping and I can't seem to get it to stop.

Also I was using **hoverblades**, if that changes anything please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure your **robo** is balanced weight wise, also having **hoverblades** is  practically useless with **helium**.